# making out program output

Tags: c++, constructor

I try to figure out output of the program without running. I'm stuck some points that first when I put a breakpoint after `const A g1;` , how come the program print output `const A 2 5` ? Second, is `B b1(a1);` same as `B b1 = a1;` in this code ? Thirdly, when a `B` obj is constructed by taking parameter an object of `A`, as you see `A` a is private member in `A` class. The `p` function doesn't execute. How come? I think it should be executed. The last one, when a `B` obj is executed(constructed), `"const B"` string literal should be printed screen out. But, It's printed just for `B b1(a1);`. Why not also `B b2(b1);` and `B b3 = b2;`?

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
class A {
public:
    A(int i = 10){ t = i; f(); p("const A ");}

    static void f(){ ++s;}
    void g() { ++t; p("func g ");}
    void operator++() {p("op++ 1 ");}
    void operator++(int) {p("op++ 2 ");}
private:
    void p(const char *t) const
    {cout << t << s << " "
        << this->t << "\n";
    }
    int t;
    static int s;
};

const A g1; // Global object


int A::s = 0;

class B {
public:
    B(A& t) : a(t)
    { cout << "const B\n"; }

private:
    A a;
};

class C{
public:
    C(B& t) : b(t)
    {
        cout << "const C\n";
    }

private:
    B b;
};

void h(A a){
    ++a;
    B b(a);
    a++;
}

static C g_c( *(new B(   *(new A(5) )  )   ) );


int main(){

    cout << "--------\n";


    {
        A::f();
        A a;
        a.f();  a.g();
    }
    cout << "--------\n";
    {
        A a;
        h(a);
    }
    cout << "--------\n";
    {
        A a1;
        A a2(a1);
        A a3 = a1;
        a2 = a1;
        cout << "--------\n";
        B b1(a1);
        B b2(b1);
        B b3 = b2;
        b2 = b1;
        cout << "--------\n";
    }
    cout << "--------\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: 4 questions is a little too many.

Comment: It will be much easier to see what's going on if you also implement the copy constructor and assignment operator.

Answer (score 0):

- You cannot put a breakpoint outside a function body. There is nothing there. Your global variables are initialised before `main` is executed. If you want to break the construction of global A `g1` put a breakpoint in A's constructor.
- `B b1(a1);` is indeed the same as  `B b1 = a1;`
- The `p` function does not execute because the new A object is copy constructed. It is not your constructor that gets executed but a copy constructor generated by the compiler. If this copy constructor does not do what you'd like it to do, write your own.
- Same answer, the first B object is constructed with your constructor, the others are copy constructed.